# Удалить директории, в которых нет определенного файла

Tags: linux, bash, логирование

Есть директория, в которую сбрасывает логи определенный "нехороший" скрипт.
Каждый из логов ложится в директорию с именем вида *2017_08_06-05_45_27_028860*.

Но дело в том, что некоторые из этих логов бесполезны, и хотелось бы их удалить не глядя. Отличительной особенностью таких логов  является отсутствие в директории файла с именем *alternative-0.htm*

Как бы сделать так, чтобы эти директории были удалены?

Comment: *[ -f "$dir/alternative-0.htm" ] || rm -fr "$dir"* Траверс по директориям сами напишите, там не сложно совсем.

Comment: [1](https://askubuntu.com/q/196960/416190) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158238/110559) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85448/110559) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вот мне интересно, `-exec` каждый раз форкает шел? Вариант с получением списка всех каталогов и потом проверки может оказаться и быстрее. (Конечно это надо проверять).

Comment: @0andriy, нет, `find -exec` вообще не использует оболочку (или в частности `system(3)`) — он сам запускает процесс через `fork()`/`exec()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментарии 0andriy предложил интересный вариант:

```
$ find . -type d | while read dir; do [ -f "$dir/alternative-0.htm" ] || rm -rf $dir; done
```